# mod_wsgi: Should the staging version of a web app be in a separate process group?

Tags: mod-wsgi

I'm trying to get familiar with Apache and mod_wsgi and I feel like I have somewhat of a grasp of how to use / think about process groups and processes:

- It seems like there's meant to be a 1-to-1 mapping of web apps to process groups: if you have different websites/web apps on your VPS, you should have each in their own process group.
- You scale the performance of each app by increasing the number of processes that the app's process group has allocated to it.  That adds additional instances of the app.  You *don't* generally want to increase the number of threads that each process has.
- If the HTTP VirtualHost for your app isn't just redirecting to the HTTPS VirtualHost, you should have both the HTTPS and HTTP version in the same process group.

However, it's not clear to me what should be done about staging environments.  I feel like they would probably qualify as being enough of a 'separate app' to warrant a separate process group, but it's not clear to me what considerations would affect the decision.  Like, I'm a bit unsure how the process group would even decide how many processes should be running each version of the app.